# Data fitting for time dependent matrix sets in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, for-loop, matrix, curve-fitting

I have 6 data sets, each data set is a 576by576 matrix. Each set of data represents measurements taken within 30 second intervals. e.g. set1 at t=0, set2 at time =30, ... ,set5 at 150 seconds.
You can look at these sets as frames if you will. I need to take first data point (1,1) from each data set -> (1,1,0), (1,1,3),(1,1,6),(1,1,9),(1,1,12),(1,1,15) and based on those 6 points find a fitting formula, then assign that general solution to the first spot of my solution matriz `SM(1,1)`. I need to do this for every data point in the 6 sets until I have a 576by576 solution matriz.

if everything goes right I should be able to plot SM(0s)=set1, SM(30s)=set2,etc. but not only that. SM(45) should return a prediction of measurements at t=45 and so on and so forth. The purpose is to have one matrix than can predict data fluctuation from time t= 0 to 150 seconds.

Additional information:
1.- Each data point is independent form the rest of the data points in the same set.
2.- it is a none-linear fit
3.- all values are real

Does Matlab have an optimization tool for this kind of problem? 
Should I treat the problem as 1D data fit and create a for loop that does the job 576^2 times?
(I don't even know where to begin)

Feel free to ask or edit anything if I wasn't clear enough. I am not sure that I've chosen the most precise title for this kind of problem.Thanks

**Update:**

Based on Guddu's answer I came up with this:

```
%% Loadint data Matrix A

A(:,:,1) = abs(set1);
A(:,:,2) = abs(set2);
A(:,:,3) = abs(set3);
A(:,:,4) = abs(set4);
A(:,:,5) = abs(set5);
A(:,:,6) = abs(set6);

%% Creating Solution Matrix B

t=0:30:150;
SM=zeros([576 576 150]);
for i=1:576
    for j=1:576
        y=squeeze(A(i,j,1:6));
        f=fit(t',y,'smoothingspline');
        data=feval(f,1:150);
        SM(i,j,:)=data;
    end
end 

%% Plotting Frame at t=45

 figure(1);
 imshow(SM(:,:,45),[])
```

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, but it works. I am open to new ideas or suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest your main data matrix would be of size (6,576,576) -> `a`. first point `(1,1)` from each dataset would be `a(1,1,1), a(2,1,1), a(3,1,1) .. a(6,1,1)`. as you have said each point `(i,j)` in each dataset from other point `(k,l)`, i would suggest treat each position `(i,j)` for all datasets separately from other positions. so it would be looping 576*576 times. code could be something like this

```
t=0:30:150;

for i=1:576
   for j=1:576
      datavec=squeeze(a(1:6,i,j)); % Select (i,j) point from all 6 frames
      % do the curve fitting and save in SM(i,j)
   end
end
```

i am just curious what kind of non-linear function you want to fit to 6 points. this might not be the answer you want but it was kind of long to put in a comment

Comment: I am trouble shooting a MRI sequence. Since this common reconstruction 576x576x150 takes too long. I am just trying to figure out a shortcut to save time.